# I'm using a devise generated view in a rails application and I keep getting nil for my name field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This view is generated with `devise`. The `email` and `password` fields are working but the `name` field returns `nil`

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%# This is for an 'organisation' model so I think the problem could be somewhere here %>
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= render "devise/shared/error_messages", resource: resource %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%# The issue is here  %>
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Comment: What is the exact error? I'd expect `resource.name` to return nil in this view, since it is a registration form and the name was not provided yet. If the `resource.name` returns `nil` after registration, do you have `:name` in the permitted attributes?

Comment: Hello @JanVítek, thank you. I'm new to devise and I hadn't added it to my permitted attributes. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Replace resource with resource_name in the form_for line:

```
<%= form_for(resource_name, resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```